# Analyze data returned from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

Sorry if this is a simple question. I have been given a stored procedure which is quite long and complex and this is returning a DataSet in a c# page. When investigating ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray, the array is full but I'm not sure which item is which in the array. Is there any efficient way how I may investigate the items which are being filled into the array and which parameter each is (e.g. name, noProducts, price, etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First look at the Columns (`Tables[0].Columns`) collection, that represents the columns that returned from your stored procedure. Then use this column names to get exact values (`Tables[0].Rows[0]["ColumnName"]`).